# Group and concatenate a 2d array by a 1d array

Tags: javascript, arrays, concatenation

I have the following arrays:

```
array_order = [ 'SiteA', 'SiteC', 'SiteB' ]

string_array = [
                [ 'Site C', 'StringC1_' ] ,
                [ 'Site A', 'StringA1_' ] ,
                [ 'Site C', 'StringC2_' ] ,
                [ 'Site B', 'StringB1_' ] ,
                [ 'Site B', 'StringB2_' ] ,
                [ 'Site B', 'StringC3_' ] ,
                [ 'Site B', 'StringA2_' ]
               ]
```

I want to group the strings by site and output them as a concatenated string in order of `array_order`, so something like this:

```
output = [ 'StringA1_StringA2_', 'StringC1_StringC2_StringC3_', 'StringB1_StringB2_' ]
```

The concatenation order doesn't matter, for example 'StringA1StringA2' is just as fine as 'StringA2StringA1' so I don't need to worry about sorting them.

I was initially thinking I could convert string_array to an object, then somehow concatenate by group, then map it something like `array_order.map(key => obj[key])` but I am struggling with making an object to be iterated and concatenated.

Comment: Is `StringC3_` supposed to be under "Site B"?, as you grouping by the letter `C` found in the string or by the "Site"?

Comment: In `array_order` you do not have space in group name, but in `string_array` you do

Comment: This entry seem to be wrong: `[ 'Site B', 'StringC3_' ] `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) on `string_array` to build your output array, we'll find the correct output index from running [Array.findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) on the `array_order` input array.

If we don't find the item, we'll skip adding it to the output:

```js
array_order = [ 'SiteA', 'SiteX', 'SiteC', 'SiteB']

string_array = [
                [ 'SiteC', 'StringC1_' ] ,
                [ 'SiteA', 'StringA1_' ] ,
                [ 'SiteC', 'StringC2_' ] ,
                [ 'SiteB', 'StringB1_' ] ,
                [ 'SiteB', 'StringB2_' ] ,
                [ 'SiteC', 'StringC3_' ] ,
                [ 'SiteA', 'StringA2_' ]
               ]
               
 let result = string_array.reduce((acc, [site, value], arr) => { 
      let index = array_order.findIndex(el => el === site);
      if (index >= 0) { 
         acc[index] = (acc[index] || "") + value;
      }
      return acc;
 }, array_order.map(el => ""))
 
 
 console.log('Result:', result);
```

And another way of doing this with [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [Array.join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join):

```js
array_order = [ 'SiteA', 'SiteX', 'SiteC', 'SiteB']

string_array = [
                [ 'SiteC', 'StringC1_' ] ,
                [ 'SiteA', 'StringA1_' ] ,
                [ 'SiteC', 'StringC2_' ] ,
                [ 'SiteB', 'StringB1_' ] ,
                [ 'SiteB', 'StringB2_' ] ,
                [ 'SiteC', 'StringC3_' ] ,
                [ 'SiteA', 'StringA2_' ]
               ]
     
let result = array_order
 .map(el => string_array.filter(([site, val]) => site === el)
 .map(([site, val]) => val)
 .join(""));
 
console.log("Result:",result);
```

Comment: how would I edit this to have a null value if there is are no matches, rather than skip it? eg `Result: [ "StringA1_StringA2_", "", "StringB1_StringB2_"]`

Comment: I've updated to leave an empty string if no matches are found.

Answer (score 2):

Yet another way:

```js
const siteOrder = ['Site A', 'Site C', 'Site B']

const strings = [
  ['Site C', 'StringC1_'],
  ['Site A', 'StringA1_'],
  ['Site C', 'StringC2_'],
  ['Site B', 'StringB1_'],
  ['Site B', 'StringB2_'],
  ['Site B', 'StringC3_'],
  ['Site B', 'StringA2_'],
]

const result = siteOrder.reduce((acc, site) => {
  acc[site] = ''
  return acc
}, {})

strings.forEach((siteString) => {
  const [site, string] = siteString
  result[site] += string
})
console.log({ result })
```

Comment: @RajdeepDebnath, I think mine is cleaner, but this is a good answer too : )

Answer (score 2):

Just use simple `map` and `reduce`

```js
array = ["Site A", "Site C", "Site B", "Site X"];

data = [
  ["Site C", "StringC1_"],
  ["Site A", "StringA1_"],
  ["Site C", "StringC2_"],
  ["Site B", "StringB1_"],
  ["Site B", "StringB2_"],
  ["Site B", "StringB3_"],
  ["Site B", "StringB4_"],
];

const output = array.map(e =>
  data.reduce((a, b) => (a += b[0] === e ? b[1] : ""), "")
);

console.log(output);
```

Comment: This one is amazing mate :)

Answer (score 1):

First yo need to group the items, then you can map each group concatenating the strings:

```js
const grouped_arrays = string_array.reduce((result, entry) => {
  const [groupName, value] = entry;
  result[groupName] = result[groupName] || [];
  result[groupName].push(value);
  return result;
}, {});

const result = array_order.map(groupName => {
  return (grouped_arrays[groupName] || []).join('');
});
```

---

Also note that your `array_order` group names do not have space: `'Site C' !== 'SiteC'`

Comment: thanks, I made a couple of typos in the question. in real life, Site C is SiteC. will try shortly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce` for this

```js
array_order = [ 'Site A', 'Site C', 'Site B' ]

string_array = [
                [ 'Site C', 'StringC1_' ] ,
                [ 'Site A', 'StringA1_' ] ,
                [ 'Site C', 'StringC2_' ] ,
                [ 'Site B', 'StringB1_' ] ,
                [ 'Site B', 'StringB2_' ] ,
                [ 'Site B', 'StringC3_' ] ,
                [ 'Site B', 'StringA2_' ]
               ]
               
let result = [...string_array.reduce((acc,[k,v]) => {
                    acc.has(k)? acc.set(k, acc.get(k)+v) : acc.set(k,v);
                    return acc;
                 }
               , new Map())]
      .sort((a,b) => array_order.indexOf(a[0])-array_order.indexOf(b[0]))
      .map(i => i[1])

console.log(result);
```